# Change in Hamiltonian under restricted canonical and symmetry transformations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

The following problem appeared in our test:

> Given the Hamiltonian $$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2q^2}{2},$$ and the generating function $$F=-\frac{Q}{q},$$ what should be the Hamiltonian in the transformed coordinates $(Q,P)$?

My Attempt:

From the generating function, we can get the following transformation equations using the equations:

$$p=\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}\\P=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial Q}$$

The transformation equations are:

$$q=\frac{1}{P}$$ $$p=P^2Q$$

Now, I am confused about how to get the Hamiltonian. There are two different ways, but the answers don't seem to match.

Method 1:

The transformation is a symmetric transformation as the generating function is time-independent. So, the Hamiltonian must be invariant. The new Hamiltonian is then given by

$$H'_1=H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2q^2}{2}$$

using the transformation equations, we get

$$H'_1=\frac{P^4Q^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2}{2P^2}$$

Method 2:

As the transformation equations do not depend on time explicitly, the transformation is a restricted canonical transformation. So, the Hamiltonian must be form invariant as we should be able to get the new Hamiltonian by just replacing q and p with Q and P respectively.

The new Hamiltonian is then given by

$$H'_2=\frac{P^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2Q^2}{2}$$

The two Hamiltonians $H'_1 \text{ and } H'_2$ do not match and I am not sure why. The answer found using Method 1 is marked as the correct one.

I am not able to find any resource that says that the Hamiltonian is form invariant under restricted canonical transformation. I came to know about it from my professor. Is it correct?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you found a fine counterexample for your misremembered/misbegotten "Method 2".

Set/nondimensionalize *m=1* and *ω=1* for notational simplicity, so
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{q^2}{2}.$$

From the restricted generating function $F=-\frac{Q}{q}$, and
$p=\frac{\partial F}{\partial q},  ~~ P=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial Q}$, you have
$$Q=pq^2, ~~~~P=1/q \\
q=\frac{1}{P}, ~~~~p=P^2Q.$$

Your [Kamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_1_generating_function) is then
$$H(q(Q,P), p(Q,P) )= H'_1(Q,P)=\frac{P^4Q^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2P^2},$$
your Method 1.

By construction, it satisfies
$$\dot{Q}=\{Q,H'_1 \}= 2Q^2 P^3 -1/P^3 \implies \\
\dot p q^2  +2pq\dot q = 2p^2q-q^3,
$$
true by the original *(q,p)* Hamilton's equations.

Now repeat for your hapless Method 2,
$$H'_2=\frac{P^2}{2}+\frac{Q^2}{2}\leadsto \\
\dot{Q}\stackrel{?}{=} \{Q,H'_2 \}= P\\
=1/q,$$
distinctly different than the left-hand-side, with translation verified above, so, equal to the r.h.side of the above Method 1.

I'm not sure what you recall, so as to rectify it, but Method 2 fails to yield the correct Hamilton's equations.